# How to choose a suitable display for pi 3 B+?

Tags: pi-3, display, pi-3b+, retropie

I'm currently looking for a display 5 inches or less for my PI, but there are a lot of information and since I'm quite new to the world of raspberry I'm looking for some help and guidance on where should I start looking for the screen.

The final configuration of the PI will be to install retroPie and assemble together with display, 8 push buttons, 6 tactile buttons, 2 joysticks, power button, 2 speakers and controllers all this with usage of some arduino stuff.

I will strip the raspberry the most I can so I can make a slim build.

1. Do all the displays require installation of drivers?
2. What options do I have to connect the display to the Pi that don't cover all GPIO connectors?

Comment: If you need to keep GPIOs available and don't want to deal with drivers, then HDMI is essentially the only sane choice. Also note that the Pi is a rather awkward choice for a project involving a battery, you'll need additional hardware for battery management.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what interface the display have. If it's a Display with HDMI it doesn't need any driver. If it's an display with SPI interface you need a driver.

PS I have a display with HDMI for the display and SPI for the "touch screen" so it can act as a mouse/digitizer.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the official 7" touch screen with a lot of success. While it is not the cheapest option, it works out of the box and it is of good quality. Because of it's configuration, it allows for all of the GPIO pins to be available as well.

Just a thought.

Comment: I agree with a 7" screen. Of course, that's because my eyes are bad enough that I can't read a smaller screen with any comfort.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you're going to install retropie and use hardware buttons.

I would filter out touch screens as they tend to get expensive (but they seem to be most common to find). Additionally, look into resolution as you probably don't need 1080p or even 720p screen. 4:3 ratio could be also useful to you as most of retro games use 4:3 and it would give you more space for buttons and less wasted screen space by black bars.

LCD is most common but OLED would save some battery if you're going to build a handheld powered by battery, tho they are more expensive than LCD ones.

Here are some I found on Aliexpress:
[5" 800x480](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000285089550.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.12913587PsyETG&algo_pvid=debcca9e-60bf-4a9d-a5a4-d81c740ea1da&algo_expid=debcca9e-60bf-4a9d-a5a4-d81c740ea1da-30&btsid=0b0a050116126221464708273e3328&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_)
[4" 800x480](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33008902594.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.6f483587HvMgcY&algo_pvid=28c04904-e626-409e-8372-767c14244dd4&algo_expid=28c04904-e626-409e-8372-767c14244dd4-20&btsid=2100bdd516126219770387466e2643&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_)
[3.5" 480x320](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000002276547.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.6f483587HvMgcY&algo_pvid=28c04904-e626-409e-8372-767c14244dd4&algo_expid=28c04904-e626-409e-8372-767c14244dd4-16&btsid=2100bdd516126219770387466e2643&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_)